# Create alarm automatically everytime Database gets new data

Tags: android, android-alarms

I need to create an alarm every time new data is inserted on the Database(the database has the values of date and time of every alarm that is going to be created), without any interaction with the user, the app has to do it automatically.

- How do I know when new data is inserted? checking every x minutes using a timer?
- How to create an alarm automatically when that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Typically for something like this, you would want to use something more like Firebase that will live update your data.

But to do a timer, first extend TimerTask:

```
public class Progress extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            //this item runs on a separate thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    seconds += 0.1;
                    //this item runs on the main thread

                }

            });
        }
    }
```

And then to run this task:

```
Timer timer;
Progress progress;
timer.schedule(progress, 100, 100);
```

This will run the timer every .1 seconds.